# declaring a struct in another struct

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

in my header file:

```
private:
struct movieNode {
    string title;

    castNode *castHead;

    movieNode *prev;
    movieNode *next;
};

struct castNode {
    string name;

    castNode *next;

};

movieNode *head;
movieNode *last;
```

but the compiler error is:

> expected ';' before '*' token

my aim is that every movieNode should have a title and a cast list (with castNode).
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`movieNode` needs to at least be able to see an incomplete type called `castNode`. At the moment, the compiler is going "Huh, `castNode`? What the hell is that?" because it hasn't seen the definition of `castNode` yet. You can avoid it in this case by simply defining `castNode` *before* you define `movieNode`. Just swap the two structs around.

In other cases, where you have a cyclic dependency (if `castNode` had a pointer to a `movieNode` too, for example), you can use a forward declaration to provide an incomplete type (it would look like `class castNode;`) and then define it properly later.

Comment: thank you, I think I am sleep walker, couldnt recognize that. thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
private:
     struct castNode; // <- add this
     struct movieNode
     {
             string     title;
             castNode*  castHead;
             movieNode* prev;
             movieNode* next;
     };
     struct castNode
     {
             string    name;
             castNode* next;
     };
     movieNode*   head;
     movieNode*   last;
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `castNode` before `movienode`.

Only then `movienode` "knows" what a `castNode` is.